# Laravel - Has many of self through

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two models, `User` and `Appointment`. Users can have clients which are also users. These clients are referenced in appointments under `client_id`:

The appointment table looks like this:

`Appointment`

`id|user_id|client_id`

I'd like to pull all clients per user (uniques) but having difficulty crafting the relationship (hasManyThrough – User has many Users (clients) through Appointments).

Based on my understanding of the Laravel docs, the following should work:

```
User.php

public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Appointment', 'client_id', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

-

```
Appointment.php

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'client_id');
}
```

Alas it does not get me what I'm looking for. Should I craft my own query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a little tricky. The documentation `Has Many Through` example is cascade like structure, which tells me that this type of relationship is not applicable to your case (but there are many undocumented things, so it could also be possible).

I propose the following relationships if you don't want to deal with undocumented cases:

**User.php**

```
public function appointmentsInWhichIsProvider()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Appointment');
}

public function appointmentsInWhichIsClient()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Appointment', 'client_id');
}
```

**Appointment.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'client_id');
}
```

If you want to get all the clients of an user, you can do something like this (not pretty at all, but should do the trick):

```
$user = User::find(1);
$userClients = [];
foreach ($user->appointmentsInWhichIsProvider as $appointment) {
    array_push($userClients, $appointment->client);
}
var_dump($userClients) // Collection containing all the user clients.
```